# Accessing Cloud Storage Objects via App Engine without making bucket publicly readable

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'd like to be able to access the files in a Cloud Storage Bucket from my App Engine App without making the objects or the bucket itself Publicly Readable. While I'm aware of a bunch of options out there that allow access to bucket objects with authentication (client libraries, signed urls, etc.), the complicating factor is that I'd like to be able to access the files with path that is similar to the folder structure of the bucket in question.

For example, if I make my bucket publicly readable, I can access objects with the public link: `https://storage.googleapis.com/MY_BUCKET/FOLDER_IN_MY_BUCKET/FILE_IN_FOLER.txt`. This url mimics the internal folder structure of the bucket. However, there doesn't appear to be a comparable url if the bucket is not publicly readable. My App Engine App service account has been added as a storage admin for the bucket I need but I'm not sure if there's a url that I can use to access the buckets objects. An object's `mediaLink` won't work because generation information is appended to the end, and `selfLink` results in a 404 error.

The need for a url like this is because the bucket contains several thousand objects. Downloading them using a client library to the the App Engine's persistent storage kind of defeats the purpose of using cloud storage in my case. Obtaining signed urls for all of them when a request is made would be time consuming and then I'd have to manage thousands of signed urls somewhere.

Is there a way to read from the cloud storage bucket with a predictable url, like the public url, while also still authenticating the request?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than trying to vend thousands of signed URLs in the response you can create a 'redirect' endpoint in your app engine app.

e.g. user does a 'GET' against `www.myapp.com/fetch/<bucket>/<object>`

Your app engine code handling this endpoint authorizes the user to make sure they should have access, pulls the bucket/object out of the URL, then generates a signed URL granting access to the resource and returns a 302 redirect to that URL.

Comment: This is a good idea, and I think this is probably the best direction to go in. However, this does require me to create a lot of signed urls. How would this option (redirecting) compare to using Google CDN, or CloudFront?

Comment: The CDN would be faster due to edge caching, but AFAIK Google CDN does not (currently) support any form of signed URL, thus you would effectively be making your bucket public, just proxied through the CDN service.

Answer (score 0):

The URL you mention can be accessed without making the bucket or file public given that your browser is authenticated with an account having access to those resources:
`https://storage.cloud.google.com/MY_BUCKET/FOLDER_IN_MY_BUCK‌​ET/FILE_IN_FOLDER`

Regarding the access to the file through a different application (for example App Engine), you can always use the [client libraries for your preferred language](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#additional_resources). You can test how the API works in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/get), just by defining the ***bucket*** parameter as *MY_BUCKET* and the ***object*** parameter as *FOLDER_IN_MY_BUCKET/FILE_IN_FOLDER*. You should use this same structure when applying it to the client library of your choice.

Comment: storage.googleapis.com does not have google cookies, and thus does not allow the user to authenticate via the browser.  They need to use OAuth (or Signed URLs) when using that endpoint.

Comment: You are right, my bad. I meant:
`https://storage.cloud.google.com/MY_BUCKET/FOLDER_IN_MY_BUCKET/FILE_IN_FOLDER`.
Let me edit my answer. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: That works, though we generally recommend against using it since it means you need to put the end users on the ACLs directly (which is not great security wise, and impossible if your end users do not have google accounts).  That endpoint also tends to be.. subtly difficult to use (you need to specify the which account should be used if the end user is logged into multiple accounts.. which is difficult... if not impossible for external users).